# Passing object to modal via resolve doesnt work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I'm learning Angular on my own and trying to edit book from selected table row. I select it properly, I have it as variable in scope, but something goes wrong when I try to pass it via resolve in `$modal.open` function.

My html, where I select a row looks like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
  <section>
      <h2>Library</h2>
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th>
              Title
            </th>
            <th>
              Author
            </th>
            <th>
              Genre
            </th>
            <th>
              Year
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-click="setSelected(book)" ng-repeat="book in books | orderBy  : 'year'">
            <td>
              <strong>{{book.title}}</strong>
            </td>
            <td>
              {{book.author}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{book.genre}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{book.year}}
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <div>
        <button ng-click="openModal()" type="button" class="btn btn- primary">Add book</button>
        <button ng-click="openEditModal()" type="button" class="btn btn- primary">Edit book</button>
      </div>
   </section>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Controllers of this html and modal are `MyfirstController` and `EditModalController` and are here:

```
angular.module('app.component1').controller('MyFirstController',    function($scope, $http, $modal, response){//tu w argumentach jeszcze byly books
'use strict';
$scope.selectedBook = null;

$scope.setSelected = function (selectedBook) {
  $scope.selectedBook = selectedBook;
};

$scope.books = response.data;

$scope.openModal = function () {
var modal = $modal.open({
 templateUrl: '/component-1/modal-dialog/modal-dialog.tpl.html',
 controller: 'MyModalController'
 /*resolve: {
            newBook: function() {
                return;
            }
        }*/
 });
 modal.result.then(function(addedBook) {
        $scope.books.push(addedBook);

    });

 };

 $scope.openEditModal = function () {
 var modal = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: '/component-1/edit-dialog/edit-dialog.tpl.html',
  controller: 'EditModalController',
  resolve: {
          selectedBook: function() {
              return $scope.selectedBook;
          }
      }
  });/*
  modal.result.then(function(addedBook) {
      $http.post('/component-1/books.json', addedBook);
  });*/

 };

}).controller('MyModalController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance',   function($scope, $modalInstance, $http){ //tu w argumentach bylo jeszcze  selectedBook
  'use strict';
  $scope.date = new Date();
  //$scope.year = $scope.date.getMonth();
  $scope.addedBook =  {
  "genre": '',
  "year": $scope.date,
  "title": '',
  "author": ''
 };
   $scope.ok = function() {
     $modalInstance.close($scope.addedBook);
   };


}]).controller('EditModalController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance',     'selectedBook', function($scope, $modalInstance, $http, selectedBook){
  'use strict';
  $scope.selectedBookTitle = selectedBook.title;
  $scope.selectedBookAuthor = selectedBook.author;
  $scope.selectedBookGenre = selectedBook.genre;
  $scope.selectedBookYear = selectedBook.year;
}]);
```

it is not important here, but he is my modal where I wanted the book data to be imported into inputs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Add new book</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <form name="modalForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input ng-model="selectedBookTitle" ng-required="true" type="text"     class="form-control" id="editTitle">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="author">Author:</label>
        <input ng-model="selectedBookAuthor" ng-required="true" type="text" class="form-control" id="editAuthor">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="genre">Genre:</label>
        <input ng-model="selectedBookGenre" type="text" class="form-control" id="editGenre">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="year">Release date:</label>
        <datepicker min="minDate" placeholder="Set release date" show-weeks="false" id="editYear"></datepicker>
        <!--<label for="year">Year:</label>-->
        <!--<input ng-model="addedBook.year" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" type="text"     class="form-control" id="year">-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer ">
        <button ng-disabled="modalForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Edit     book</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't look at `datepickers`. I need to think long about them, and how to make them working as I'd like them to.

So let's come back to the `openEditModal()` and resolve. I'm getting error that angular can't read property title in `selectedBook.title` in `EditModalController` or it is undefined. I'm sure I have an error in resolve in `openEditModal`, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: For your `EditModalController`, the injected array `'$scope', '$modalInstance', 'selectedBook'` does not match the parameter list `function($scope, $modalInstance, $http, selectedBook)`.

Comment: I've changed it into ['$scope', '$modalInstance', '$http', 'selectedBook', function($scope, $modalInstance, $http, selectedBook) and I still have the same problem. And in MyModalController I also hadn't '$http' in this table, but it works :(

Comment: ok, it started to work. I guess it wasn't working after the change because of the browser cache, but after cleaning it, it seems, that it was enough to add this $http. Thank you :)